# No architectures to compile for core plot iphone

Tags: iphone, compilation, core-plot

I'm trying out a core plot iphone example and I get:

No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=i386, VALID_ARCHS=armv6 armv7).

Under project settings -> architecture, the only options are standard, optimized, and native arch.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was getting the same error while trying to run some older sample code...  It turns out that the project build settings get changed (by the iOS 4.1 SDK?).  Anyway, changing these settings back worked for me:

ORIG PROJECT "BUILD" SETTINGS:

> > Architecture:  $(NATIVE_ARCH)

and

> > Valid Architectures:  i386

NEW SETTINGS:

> > Architectures: armv6 armv7

and

> > Valid Architectures:  armv6 armv7 i386

Just like magic...

~Paul

Answer (score 6):

Add i386 to Valid Architectures